# Windows 8 metro style apps and window hooks

Tags: hook, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am new to both window hooks and Windows 8 metro apps..

I would like to develop a background service/process that:

1. Checks the "properties" of the metro app that a user just tapped to start (e.g. app that plays music, text document creator app, ...)
2. Based on the properties found, activate other applications (i.e., before starting the text creator application that the user just tapped, make him select the font face from a popup list)

I am planning on using window hooks to do 1 and 2..

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you refer to **window hooks** or some other kind of hooks on Windows? You can hook functions, which requires some hackery or you can set hooks on windows (the "objects"), which are called **window hooks**, though.

Comment: I am referring to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589(v=vs.85).aspx) kind of hook... Is that the same with "window hooks"? I would like to use the system kind, and not the application-dependent kind....

Comment: yes, those are called commonly called "window hooks", while Windows (as in the trademark) will lead to ambiguity and confusion :)

Comment: This is exactly the sort of instability that the new application model is trying to prevent. Imagine if this were possible -- applications would be hijacking each other left and right. "Oh, the user clicked on Contoso? Let me intercept it and launch LitWare instead, because Contoso is our direct competitor and we want to hurt them."

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to hook Windows or intercept the launching of a Metro style app from within a Metro style app itself.  While it may be possible to do so with a service installed on the machine in a classic way, doing so would be totally undocumented and unsupported.  You would have to reverse-engineer the app launching process to have any chance at making it work.

Comment: Remember that services run in session 0 and can't interact with desktop windows.

Comment: @Larry, I am not really sure what you mean by your comment.... Can you point me to some materials that might help me understand? Thanks!

Comment: Steve mentioned using a service to hook stuff - I was just pointing out that since Windows Vista, services have no access to interactive applications.   There really is no way of doing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out..

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/43df6c8f-f1e3-4aba-af0a-7c4e1db477b6

> You can only write client applications using Metro, not server applications.

In your scenario, if you want inter-app communication, recommended way is to use 'Contracts' which are explicitly started by the user.

I'm taking a blind guess here using your 1 and 2 points. Do you intend to handle a specific file type ? say .txt or .wmv  ?
If this is your intention, please check here http://tozon.info/blog/post/2011/10/11/Windows-8-Metro-declarations-File-Type-Associations.aspx
There's also a good set of MSDN documentation about this.

Answer (score 0):

You may use API hooking. Check this thread:
http://forum.nektra.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=6228