# How to detect metro application close from win32 process in windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-8, microsoft-metro, win32-process

Win32 application has application ID of a random metro application. Win32 application should detect if the application with given ID was closed by a user. Metro application process is running on windows 8.1 (unlike windows 8) even after close by a user.

According to this article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx
"In Windows 8.1 and later, after an app has been closed by the user, the app is only removed from the screen and switch list without being terminated."

"There's no special event to indicate that the user has closed an app."

Are there other ways to detect metro app close on windows 8.1 from win32 process?

Comment: Did You try to solve it with global windows hooks ?

Comment: @icbytes I don't know what to track except user actions that close metro app. Some of user actions are hard to track: close via context menu from running apps list; close via gesture (it's necessary to know sizes of lines that causes application close, they may differ on different environments)

Comment: Start reading about hooks ( perhaps here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959(v=vs.85).aspx#whgetmessagehook ).
But this speaks against hooks.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596243/windows-8-metro-style-apps-and-window-hooks

Comment: The problem is in what exact window and message can be used for app close detection. There is window with ImmersiveSwitchList class that could be used for close detection , but it seems that it doesn't exist all the time(it exist only when it is visible) when detection is required.

Comment: Try to use WM_CLOSE / WM_PAINT .....

Comment: @icbytes Exactly how does `WM_PAINT` help solve the question (or hooks, for that matter)? Are you just guessing or do you have a working proof of concept?

Comment: Sounds like a job for [WinEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373889(v=vs.85).aspx); EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY, in particular.  Raymond Chen has a [quick walkthrough](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/10/28/10230020.aspx) that should help.